# Search function with whitespace

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build an online dictionary which take input from user and trace back to database then print the output like the input, but the problem is if the user type more than 2 whitespace (i.e John  Wick), the result return not found (in my database is John Wick). Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT `E_word`,`V_word` FROM word WHERE `V_word` REGEXP '$word'";
```

where $word is the input variable from user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`preg_replace`** before sending variable to `SQL Query` and convert multiple spaces to single spaces.

```
$word = 'John   Wick';
$result = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $word );

var_dump($result);
```

**`Output:`**

**John Wick**

Also use wildcard `%` with query

```
$query = "SELECT `E_word`,`V_word` FROM word WHERE `V_word` LIKE '".$result."%'";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you explain why we have to use the wildcard place there

Comment: let suppose `John Wick danny` in `V_word` and using wildcard in the end `LIKE 'John Wick%'` it will give you two records one with `John Wick` and another will be `John Wick danny`

Comment: the $result is working well, but it seems i cant still make it run well, it still return not found even when $result have value exactly like in database

Comment: can you please updated your question with table schema and data ?